# How to fetch a property into text field?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

How to fetch `<s:property value="userPojo.registerno"/>` into text field?

Code is here:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<body bgcolor='cyan'>
  <center>
    <font color='green' size="5pxl"><u><b>User Edit form</b></u></font><br>
    <s:form action="newuser">
      <table border="0" background="red" cellpadding="5">
        <tr><td>
          <s:textfield name="regnumber" label="Registration Number"
             id="regnumber" value="<s:property value='userPojo.regnumber'/>"/>
        </td></tr>
      </table>
    </s:form>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17733505/1700321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the struts tags you don't need to and you can't use `s:property` tag to write a value into the `value` attribute. You can get a value via OGNL expression. Also note, the value attribute is used to define a default value for the field that overrides the value used by the `name` attribute. Your name attribute differs from value attribute, so you should have both properties defined with getters and setters. The `name` attribute is used to set a value from textfield when you submit the form.

```
<s:textfield name="regnumber" label="Registration Number" id="regnumber" value="%{userPojo.regnumber}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Roman C. Explanation and solution has given me alot of concept and resolved my problem. i have been suffered from last night.

Comment: @Skumar If it helped you to solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted. If you are new to SO you should get know [how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sorry Mr. Roman C, I am new here.. i clicked on up arrow button. please check it once it accepted or not..

Comment: Up arrow doesn't work yet, it would work if you have enough rep, but you can use checkbox below the arrows. You should better read the link provided in the comment above and take it seriously. If you accept the answer you shouldn't undo it. You can read what happens if you will play with it http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260990/accepted-and-unaccepted-for-the-same-answer

Comment: Thanks once again Mr. Roman C. Its clear for me now even i checked the check box and it becomes Green in color. But please if you don't mined could you tell me the meaning of reputation here. i didn't get. i am using this very first time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/573032)